# Kivy canvas doesn't fit to the parent layout

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to make a trial canvas (having just yellow rectangle as bounding box) which should fit to the parent layout (in this case FloatLayout).

1. At the beginning, the canvas is created at `[0,0]` of size `[100,100]`. 2) If I resize by dragging the App window corners, the canvas resizes well. However, 3) & 4) if I maximize or minimize, the canvas fails to resize properly. So as weird canvas size is noticed if I drag too fast. Any help would be highly appreciated :)

Please note `create_canvas` method an example and it should be in the `main.py`.

[image]

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions import Line
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.graphics import InstructionGroup, Color


class TestOut(BoxLayout):
    canvas_items = InstructionGroup()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.create_canvas(pos=[dp(150), dp(0)], size=[dp(650), dp(500)])

    def on_size(self, *args):
        self.can_obj = self.ids.can
        # print(self.can_obj.pos, self.can_obj.size)

        self.canvas_items.clear()
        self.can_obj.canvas.clear()
        self.create_canvas(self.can_obj.pos, self.can_obj.size)

    def create_canvas(self, pos, size):
        self.canvas_items.add(Color(1, 1, 0, 1))
        self.canvas_items.add(Line(rectangle=(pos[0], pos[1], size[0], size[1]), width=5))
        self.canvas.add(self.canvas_items)


class PlaygroundApp(App):
    title = "blabla"

    def build(self):
        return TestOut()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    PlaygroundApp().run()
```

playground.kv

```
<TestOut>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Button:
        id: button1
        text:'A'
        height: dp(100)
        size_hint: 1, None
        pos_hint:  {'top':1}

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        Button:
            id: button2
            text:'B'
            width: dp(150)
            size_hint: None, 1
        FloatLayout:
            id: can
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you want the `rectangle` size to follow the `FloatLayout` size, but your `on_size()` is triggered by changes in the size of `TestOut`. One easy fix is to just remove the canvas drawing from the python and put the `rectangle` in the `kv`, like this:

```
    FloatLayout:
        id: can
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 1, 0, 1
            Line:
                width: 5
                rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
```

A different fix (that leaves the canvas drawing in the python), is to trigger on the size of the `FloatLayout`. First, change the name of `on_size()` to something else, say `do_on_size()`:

```
def do_on_size(self, *args):  # changed name to eliminate dependency on size of TestOut
    self.can_obj = self.ids.can
    # print('on_size:', self.can_obj.pos, self.can_obj.size)

    self.canvas_items.clear()
    self.can_obj.canvas.clear()
    self.create_canvas(self.can_obj.pos, self.can_obj.size)
```

Then add some code in the `PlaygroundApp` to set the binding to the size of the `FloatLayout`:

```
class PlaygroundApp(App):
    title = "blabla"

    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.set_binding)
        return TestOut()

    def set_binding(self, dt):
        fl = self.root.ids.can
        fl.bind(size=self.root.do_on_size)
```